How to handle folders and subfolders in a container (AzureBlob) from powerapps
We have 2 containers each container has parent folders and sub-folders in it.
The sub-folders have the files.
By using the following code we can access containers in Blob Storage:
{AzureBlobStorage.ListRootFolderV2().value}

By using the following code we can access parent folders in the containers:
{ForAll(
    AzureBlobStorage.ListFolderV2(Gallery1.Selected.Name).value,
    { Name: Left(Name, Len(Name) - 1) }

We are trying to access sub-folders in the parent folders by using below code but it showing the error
{Filter(
    ForAll(
        AzureBlobStorage.ListFolderV2(Gallery2.Selected.Name).value,
        { Name: Left(Name, Len(Name) - 1) }
    ),
    StartsWith(Name, Gallery2.Selected.Name & "/") && Len(Name) > Len(Gallery2.Selected.Name)
)}

Error: AzureBlobStorage.ListFolderV2 failed "Status": 404 specified container does not exist
The container is valid but not sure what is causing this issue. Any suggestions

The above error might be due to the different Gallery.
As per this ask by @DaveC82,
The below query will give the list of all the file paths in the given container which you can use as per your requirement.
AzureBlobStorage.ListFolderV2("<your_storage_account_name>", "<container_name>", {nextPageMarker: "", useFlatListing: true}).value

This will return all the file paths by flat listing like below.
container1/folder1/sub-folder1/file1.csv
container1/folder1/sub-folder2/file2.csv
container2/folder2/sub-folder3/file1.csv
.
.

You need to give your container names in a loop and apply this logic to get all file paths in the container. If there is a need to get file paths from a specific folder, you can apply filter on this list as per your requirement.
